# Android. Свой экран блокировки. Кнопка "Home"

Tags: android, безопасность

Необходимо заблокировать кнопку Home когда включен мой экран блокировки. Как я понимаю, просто так нельзя заблокировать кнопку "Home", но можно дать пользователю выбор, что должно происходить при нажатии на кнопку "Home". Если он выберет мое приложение,  он ВСЕГДА будет переходить на мой экран. Это не очень вариант. Может кто знает как можно такое реализовать?

Например, есть приложение Go Locker, который сначала запрашивает что использовать при нажатии на "Home". Но когда экран Go Locker'a не включен, при нажатии на "Home" происходит переход на обычный Home Screen. Не могу понять, как они так сделали(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911049/create-custom-lockscreen-for-android-4-0-or-above  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864300/create-a-lock-screen-of-my-own

Comment: есть один хороший вариант - собрать свою сборку андроида. Там это можно решить гарантировано. А все другое - это костыли, как например у Самсунга получается (а потом можно поменять все, не разблокируя до конца.

Comment: KoVadim, костыли бы тоже не помешали, например интересно как реализован вариант у Go Locker(описал в правке).

Comment: Andreich, в первой ссылке есть решение только для android ниже 4й версии. Во второй половина ссылок с пустыми репозиториями, в другой половине нет решений данной проблемы.